# Cannot redirect python script output to infile

Tags: python, linux

I am working on Debian Stable Linux which is otherwise working very well. I have following code in a python script file named "myrev" which works to reverse order of lines of given text file:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3 

import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2: 
    print("Usage: myrev infile")
    sys.exit()
try:
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().split("\n")
except: 
    print("Unable to read infile.")
    sys.exit()

lines.reverse()
print("\n".join(lines))
```

It works properly and prints out reverse order of lines if I use following Linux command

```
./myrev infile
```

However, if I try to redirect output with following command to original file, a blank file is generated:

```
./myrev infile > infile
```

After above command, infile becomes an empty file.

Why can't I redirect output to original file and how can this be solved?

Comment: Maybe this is better suited to [SU]. `cat infile > infile` behaves the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash) and [Why is writing to a file from my python script getting overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40620713/608639).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `>` opens the target file for write, same as if opened via `fopen` with mode `"w"`. That *immediately* truncates the file, before your program even launches (it happens while the shell is configuring the environment before `exec`ing your program). You can't use this approach to read from a file and replace it as a single step. Best you could do would be something like:

```
./myrev infile > infile.tmp && mv -f infile.tmp infile
```

where, if the command succeeds, you complete the work by replacing the original file with the contents of the new file.

Comment: I did'nt realized Linux was truncating infile before executing python script.